# how to display different DIV part on clicking different <li> links in same JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I want to display a different image in JSP on clicking a different links in the same JSP.
Can any one please help me in displaying image with respect to the DIV id.

here are my links bellow

```
<table class="contentTable" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=0 border=0 >
        <tr class="altRow1">

            <th class="fieldName" nowrap="nowrap" align="center" colspan="<%=metricCols %>">Business statistics </th>
        </tr>

<tr>

<div class="greyBorderBox bottomSpacer10">



<ul class="noBullet" >

             <li class="nav-off" ><a class="headerNav-myworkspace" href="#" onClick="show_app1(this.id);" id="id_1">link1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-off" ><a  class="headerNav-myworkspace" href="#" onClick="show_app2(this.id);" id="id_2">link2</a></li>

</ul></td></tr>
```

below are the two DIV parts to be displayed

```
<tr class="altRow1">

<!-- if link1 is clicked this part should be displayed -->

    <%if(bus.exists())){ %>
        <div id="id1"> <td class="fieldName" style="vertical-align:top;" id="id1">
                      <a href="C:\Users\Desktop\graph.GIF" target="_blank"><img height="240px" src= "C:\Users\Desktop\graph.GIF" style="align:'center';" ></img></a>
            </td></div>

<!-- if link2 is clicked this part should be displayed -->

<% }else {  %>

                <div id="id2"><td class="fieldName" style="vertical-align:top;">
                      <a href="C:\Users\Desktop\Capture.GIF" target="_blank"><img height="240px" src= "C:\Users\Desktop\Capture.GIF" style="align:'center';" ></img></a>

                </td>
            <%
            }


</div>  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put user defined attribute inside link and send only `this` param as a references like so :

```
<li class="nav-off" ><a class="headerNav-myworkspace" href="#" onClick="show_app(this);" id="id_1" data-target="id1">link1</a></li>
<li class="nav-off" ><a  class="headerNav-myworkspace" href="#" onClick="show_app(this);" id="id_2" data-target="id2">link2</a></li>
```

One more thing, `id` should be unique(remove `id="id1"` inside img tag), change into this :

```
<div id="id1" style="display:none"> 
 <td class="fieldName" style="vertical-align:top;" > 
 <a href="C:\Users\Desktop\graph.GIF" target="_blank"><img height="240px" src= "C:\Users\Desktop\graph.GIF" style="align:'center';" ></img>
 </a>
 </td>
</div>
```

For initial state, just hidden those two div using `style="display:none"`, see above code. Same applied for second div.

And **JS** would be :

```
 <script>
 function show_app(e){
   var target = $(e).data('target');
   $('#'+target).toggle();
   // ... another rest of code
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but this not working for me. Can you pls check  http://jsfiddle.net/S7K4r/160/

Comment: I am using style="display:none to hide image.. Image is not loading once after clicking. Is there any other way to hide image until the click.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8p2h21ga/2/)**

Added `#id1, #id2` in href of `<a>` and used those `id's` for `<div>`

```
 <ul class="noBullet" >
     <li class="nav-off" ><a class="headerNav-myworkspace" href="#id1">link1</a></li>
     <li class="nav-off" ><a  class="headerNav-myworkspace" href="#id2">link2</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div id="id1">test 1 </div>
 <div id="id2">test 2 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. test1 and test2 are displayed on load. Can you please tell me how to display test1 by default on load, but test2 to be displayed only on clicking link2. test2 should replace the test1 place on clicking link2.